# Spivak GENERAL limit law proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Suppose $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all real $x$ Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \le \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$

Let limit for $f(x)$ be denoted by $L$

Let limit for $g(x)$ be denoted by $M$.

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $|x - a| < \delta_1$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} g(x) \implies |g(x) - M| < \epsilon$ for $|x - a| < \delta_2$

We must prove that $L \le M$ right?

So what are the ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove by contradiction.

Let $h=g-f\ge 0$ for all $x$, claim $D=\lim_{x\to a}h(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)-\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=M-L\ge 0$

Suppose not, $D<0$ then by definition of convergence, you can find a neighborhood of $a$ such that $h<\frac{D}{2}<0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: But how can you assume $L < 0$?

Comment: @Amad27 I try to prove by contradiction. That is I suppose the conclusion ($L\ge 0$) doesn't hold, and try to use it to derive a contradiction.

Comment: but the point is to prove $L < M$, not that $L \ge 0$

Comment: That is the $L, M$ is my original question.

Comment: @Amad27 My notation is different from yours. I have updated your answer to make it clearer.

Comment: thanks. I still don't understand a few things, would you mind helping me out. If you can prove that $D > 0$ then how would that prove $L < M$?

Answer (score 2):

If $0 < |x-a| < \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ then $$L = (L - f(x)) + f(x) < \epsilon + g(x) = \epsilon + (g(x) - M) + M < 2\epsilon + M.$$
This inequality is independent of $x$ so you can let $\epsilon \searrow 0$. Thus $L \le M$.